# Module parse failed: Parenthesized pattern You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: angular, webpack

I have created a brand new angular 2 application using these commands:

```
ng init
ng server
```

I get this error output:

```
chunk    {1} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.map (styles) 9.96 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.map (vendor) 2.65 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]
ERROR in ./~/@angular/core/src/util/decorators.js
Module parse failed: /Users/nikolaschou/Dev/coziv/sandbox01/blockhowapp/temp/node_modules/@angular/core/src/util/decorators.js Parenthesized pattern (156:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|if (clsDef.hasOwnProperty('extends')) {
|  if (typeof clsDef.extends === 'function') {
```

Can anyone explain why I might get this error? I see a lot of similar errors reported, but not exactly this variation.

**More details**

I can say that ng serve works well from another angular-2 application folder on the same machine and I have compared these two folders but don't see any obvious differences that can explain this behavior.

I use a Mac with latest iOS and this is the output from ng --version:

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.26
node: 6.6.0
os: darwin x64
@angular/common: 2.4.5
@angular/compiler: 2.4.5
@angular/core: 2.4.5
@angular/forms: 2.4.5
@angular/http: 2.4.5
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.5
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.5
@angular/router: 3.4.5
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.5
```

Comment: Which version of webpack are you using? We're hitting a similar issue with a webpack/backbone setup.

Comment: We also just started seeing this. Using webpack 2.2.0. I'm guessing someone's transitive dependency upgraded and is breaking things..

Comment: Latest @angular/cli beta.29, webpack 2.2.0 - same thing

Comment: related issue on github: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4378

Comment: I think it might be https://www.npmjs.com/package/acorn ? Recently updated from 4.0.4 to 4.0.5

Yes. See this issue here: https://github.com/ternjs/acorn/issues/502

Answer (score 14):

The dependency that caused this to fail is now updated. If you uninstall webpack and reinstall webpack it will update acorn to version 4.0.7. This should solve your issue.

https://github.com/ternjs/acorn/issues/502

or just run

`npm i acorn@4.0.8` from the project directory (thanks @nodarii)

Comment: just run `npm i acorn@4.0.7` from the project directory

Comment: I should add that I just ran npm i acorn@4.0.7 and immediately after this ng serve worked again.

Comment: They were some lingering issues with acorn@4.0.7 - they've just released 4.0.8 which fixes everything. I've updated my answer.